# jsPlumb Posse Example

Tags: draggable, jsplumb

Does anyone know of a working example for jsPlumbs Posses feature?

*Since jsPlumb 2.0.0 there is another way of configuring multiple element drag - the concept of a posse. This is a group of elements that should all move whenever one of them is dragged. This mechanism is intended to be used for more "permanent" multiple drag arrangements - you may have a set of nodes that should always move together and they do not need to be considered to be "selected".*

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/dragging.html